# What are the software logos in MORICONS.DLL?

Tags: history, windows-3.x, identify-this-software

Every copy of Windows comes with a file named MORICONS.DLL which was first distributed with Windows 3.0. As far as I know, this file has not been changed since Windows 3.0. Some of the icons include:

- Borland C++
- Kid Pix
- Quicken
- All the Lotus products available at the time (Freelance Graphics, cc:Mail, 1-2-3, Magellan)
- [Gazelle Q-DOS](https://winworldpc.com/product/gazelle-q-dos/3x) (the blue, file tree-looking icon. It's a directory manager program)
- Over a dozen WordPerfect-related icons
- FoxPro
- Borland Sidekick
- Paradox 4.0

However, there are some I only vaguely recognize:

- Another Gazelle product: Back-It or OPTune?
- Two other directory managers
- A Digital product related to X-Windows
- An XcelleNet product
- An shaded icon with the letters "ADOS" on it -- possibly a predecessor to OS/2?
- Several different variations of extremely '90s-looking abstract squiggles
- Other completely mysterious icons, many proclaiming themselves to be Microsoft products for DOS

If anyone can provide more details on any of these icons, please let me know. You can check your own copy of Windows for the MORICONS.DLL file.

Comment: I guess whoever invented that name does not know the word maricon...as a teen it was a running joke.

Comment: @Rui not everyone speaks Spanish ;-).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it's an unfortunate artifact of the 8.3 filename restrictions from DOS days. They couldn't call it `MOREICONS.DLL` because that'd be 9 characters, and `MOREICON.DLL` is weird because the icons are definitely plural. Perhaps a better contraction (which generally is accomplished by omitting vowels) would've been `MOREICNS.DLL`...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You’ll find the mappings for these icons in `SYSTEM\APPS.INF` in Windows 3; this is the file which is used by Windows Setup to detect pre-existing DOS applications on the system, and set up icons for them in Program Manager. Look for “moricons.dll” and the index of the icon you’re interested in.

For example the ADOS icon, index 101, corresponds to Access for DOS.

Comment: Thanks! Here are the mysterious squiggles, then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datastorm_Technologies

Answer (score 139):

I wrote a short python script that extracted the icons, matched them with entries from `APPS.INF` and generated an HTML file. Some entries were missing, so I entered them manually, except for the generic MS-DOS icons which I marked as "(no entry)". One icon was blank. You can find my [moricons.py script on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/isanae/caee5d1c727fd9fdc48a3d80055d3600).

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78899/discussion-on-answer-by-isanae-what-are-the-software-logos-in-moricons-dll).

Comment: What's with that Wonky MS-DOS icon? I saw that logo as a child when I found Kid Pix stopped working for some reason. I just assumed something had gone and corrupted the executable and the icon.

Comment: @Wilson Which one?

Comment: The second one from the left, on the first row.

Comment: @Wilson That's the [MS-DOS logo](https://cdn.instructables.com/F2A/21OA/H3NLEZI8/F2A21OAH3NLEZI8.LARGE.jpg).

Comment: Is that all? I remember the MS DOS logo looking much straighter and neater.

Comment: @Wilson There's a bunch of them. That's the 6.22 logo.

Comment: I will note for posterity that "DWINFO3" is a diagnostic tool for "PC DECwindows Motif". It is indeed an X11 server for MS-DOS, programmed by Digital.